# Bad operand types for binary type using Mutator in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I'm a beginner to Java programming. I'm using the BlueJ IDE. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this mutator. The error message says `bad operand types for binary types`.

```
/**
 * Sets the period of this course.
 */
public void setPeriod(String period)
{
    if(period = "A"|| "B" || "C" || "D")
    {
        this.period = period;
    }
} // end of mutator setPeriod(String period)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `if` statement expression is incorrect.  Separate test expressions need to be delimited with the logical `||` operator.

Also use `String.equals` for comparing `String` content. The assignment operator `=` is is used to assign values.

```
if (period.equals("A") || period.equals("B") || 
                          period.equals("C") || period.equals("D")) {
```

*or* better

```
if ("A".equals(period) || "B".equals(period) || 
                          "C".equals(period) || "D".equals(period)) {
```

This will protect against `NullPointerException` should `period` be `null`

Answer (score 4):

`||` stands for **logical OR** and its operands can be **boolean** or an **expression** which results in **boolean**

You should change your method to check boolean expressions like below

```
public void setPeriod(String period)
{
    if("A".equals(period) || "B".equals(period) || "C".equls(period) || "D".equals(period)) // using "A".equals(period) also gives safety from NPE, if period is null
    {
        this.period = period;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will want to consult the [operator precedence table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).  Logical or, `||` has higher precedence than assignment, `=`.  Also, you need to recognize that in the `C` family of languages, `=` is assignment, while `==` is the equality test.  So, your expression

```
if(period = "A"|| "B" || "C" || "D")
```

means the same as

```
if(period = ("A"|| "B" || "C" || "D"))
```

*set period to "A" or "B" or "C" or "D"* and see if the result is `true`.  But logical or only works with booleans, unlike C, so that that part of the expression won't compile.  Even if that worked, you would be setting period to the result instead of testing it.  And then the result wouldn't be a boolean.

What you need is to test for set membership:

```
private final Set<String> legalPeriods;
static {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add("A");
    set.add("B");
    set.add("C");
    set.add("D");
    legalPeriods = Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
}
```

Then, write your test as:

```
if (legalPeriods.contains(period)) {
    this.period = period;
}
```

This is more work, but it explains itself very well.  The call to `unmodifiableSet` is disaster-proofing; i try to protect myself against myself.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void setPeriod(String period)
{
    if(period.equals("A") || period.equals("B") || period.equls("C") || period.equals("D"))
    {
        this.period = period;
    }
} // end of mutator setPeriod(String period)
```

So what happens if period is null?  Or not equal to any of those values?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you would avoid the problem and generally make things easier for yourself if you were to use an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of a string for periods. Then you could use, for example, the static [valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) method for parsing strings from input files:

```
public void setPeriod(String period) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    this.period = Enum.valueOf(Class<Period>, period);
}
```

or you could just have your method be:

```
public void setPeriod(Period period) {
    this.period = period;
}
```

and not worry about it when writing your class.